# ASPX embedded resource not showing

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, iis, embedded-resource

I am using a ASPX page as a embedded resource for displaying that in a iframe on a separate page. **Works absolutely fine on all the development machines**. Even if i host that **in IIS in my machine**, it works fine . But it doesn't work on Production machine . Is there a configuration that could be different in both the machine. Can somebody provide suggestions on where to look for the problem?

Comment: please provide some code. And can you explain what you mean by embedded resource? Is it compiled into our dll?

Comment: Yes you are right it is compiled into the DLL. There is no code to this because we dont have to write code to make it a embedded resource. Its a property setting.

Comment: How do you read that embedded resource? Are you sure that it comes out of the dll, or is it fetched from your hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

difficult to say without any code, but perhaps worth checking the trust level of your provider (perhaps they only have medium trust, which might affect parts of your application)

Comment: I checked the trust levels they are set to FULL.